# Can I make my PC a Lich's Phylactery?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

I came up with the idea on a car ride am genuinely curious. I know it states that it needs to be a box with magical scrolls (but in certain editions it can be an item as well like a coin or an amulet) so I'm wondering if a person/creature could have been made by a Lich in order to keep it's life force somewhere? Or even have the phylactery made into the body, so it never stays in one place and the Lich doesn't have to worry about it getting destroyed by someone. Mainly it would be a fun role playing idea, but I don't know if it's a feasible concept, nor if the full logistics could make entire sense. But hey, can't hurt to get second opinions!

I'm a 5e player as it was what I was introduced to

Comment: Hi Necrodruidism, I assume you are the same user as "user60910". If so, currently this question belongs to your first account (hence why your edit had to go through an edit review) and does not belong to your second account "Necrodruidism", so you won't be able to comment on this post, make edits (without going through edit reviews) or accept your favourite answer (once this question has some answers). I recommend you get your accounts merged - see [this help page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to do so.

Answer (score 8):

## Even if this was possible, it makes no real sense

The whole idea of a phylactery is that it keeps the Lich's soul safe. You put it in a safe location where nobody will find it and then protect that place with wards, ensuring that if your undead body gets obliterated, it can be reformed next to that phylactery, in a secret location with traps to protect you.

You, instead, wish to make your phylactery a squishy bag of flesh who is prone to getting killed in an accident. Even if your squishy soulbag doesn't get themselves killed in one of the many bandit raids, orc ambushes and dragon assaults, you have no idea where your body is going to reform if you do kick the bucket.

The rules don't really support people being a phylactery, either, even if it was a good idea.

> A phylactery is traditionally an amulet in the shape of a small box, but it can take the form of any item possessing an interior space into which arcane sigils of naming, binding, immortality, and dark magic are scribed in silver.

They might count if they're a Warforged, but your mileage may vary. It's up to your DM if the insides of your character count as 'an item' and if having 'dark magic inscribed in silver' inside of your body is good for you.

If your Lich is absolutely dead-set on gambling with their soul and continued existence, it'd make far more sense to have that PC wear a necklace that is the actual phylactery, some sort of family heirloom they'd never get rid of. That way, at least your phylactery can't die because it didn't pay attention while crossing a road.

Comment: Furthermore, from the MM: "_A phylactery is traditionally an amulet in the shape of a small box, but it can take the form of **any item possessing an interior space into which arcane sigils of naming, binding, immortality, and dark magic are scribed in silver.**_" - I don't think a PC can satisfy that requirement...

Comment: Yeah didn't even bother to add that because the idea just made no sense, but it's most likely smart to point out that it's also not possible in the rule sense.

Comment: *Any item possessing an interior space into which arcane sigils [...] are scribed?* Many D&D monsters use thematically crafted items out of skulls. Get a "recently liberated" skull, craft it into a phylactery. Then use a spell which can revive the dead- ideally one that reforms around remaining body parts such as one of the uses of True-Resurrection. Perhaps reinforce that skull with something a little sturdier than bone when the opportunity presents itself, for the same reasons Theik pointed out. Viola? Even if the person dies (again) it's the skull that's the important part.

Comment: Technically people could satisfy the requirement, depending on the amount of place needed. You could put the sigils on somebody's teeth (or in more extreme cases bones).

Comment: Along with the skull points, the warforged briefly mentioned is also a good point in a potential way something like this could perhaps work too. Being sturdier (likely to survive the poorly crossing a road point etc.) and easier to get silver arcane runes on too, to be a mobile and self-defending phylactery.

Comment: Plus, phylacteries are supposed to last a long time (the point is *immortality*, after all). Making one out of a *mortal* presents some time limits on that, made even worse by the fact that it's clear new phylacteries could be made.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely**

A phylactery need only be *any item possessing an interior space into which arcane sigils of naming, binding, immortality, and dark magic are scribed in silver.*

People have interior space. In their skulls, in their stomachs, in their bones, really all over if you have the right mindset.
So the only thing stopping a person from being a phylactery is that phylacteries are made from **items**. Liches, however, have spells from the wizard list. Including both True Polymorph and Flesh to Stone - both of which can turn creatures into objects (items) for an indefinite period of time.

So it's absolutely possible.

---

But as a discerning Lich, I have some more requirements to make it *feasible*. A phyl-lackey has several benefits over the traditional version - it can follow you like an underling, it can actually defend itself, and it can even flee a dangerous situation.
However, it can also wander off and get lost, captured, or killed.
Now the obvious solution to this is to find someone who's got a perpetual death wish. Like a Zealot Barbarian! They love dying. And even better, it's *totally free* to bring them back - via Clone or even True Resurrection if you take the time to go... *convince*...  a Cleric to help out.
You just have to tangle up your phylactery magic with their soul to make sure both come back to you.

Just imagine the look on your enemies faces. They've got your phylactery, they kill the guy, they research up some ancient magic to dispel your soulbinding, and whoosh! Off flies the soul of the recently departed back to you, phylactery safe and sound in his new body.

Boy it's gotta suck to be mortal.

Comment: Wouldn't reverting the object (item) back to a creature (not-item) be a problem of invalid target for the phylactery?

Comment: The mechanics of phylacteries aren't explored enough in mechanics to answer that question. It's not a spell, so it doesn't fall under spell targeting rules, and if you choose to use something like the skull the *item* is still clearly there, just surrounded by fleshy bits that cause it to move - it'd be just like carrying an amulet enclosed in your hand. Of course, as the discerning lich I am I'd make plenty of test subjects before releasing my final product into the world. Gotta be sure of yourself, you know?

Comment: My favorite is still a golem's hollow shin.